# How to remove put from a pre written view in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following view:

```
class ReadClass(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = MyCModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         ''' defined my post here'''
```

I know `retrieveupdatedestroyapi`view doesn't have post in it. And I have created my own post in the view here and on the front end, I see both post and put! Is there any way to remove the put.

Or is there any other way to do it better, I tried using `ListCreateApi view`. The problem with that is while it gives me the post functionality, it lists all the values, while I am looking for a specific `pk`. I cannot see any other generic view that gives me `get` and `post` functionality.

**EDIT**

I have added the edit as requested, try and except might seem unnecessary here at the moment, but I will add more functionality later on.

```
class ReadClass(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin):
    queryset = MyCModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            s1 = MySerializer.objects.get(mRID=kwargs["pk"])
            serializer = MySerializer(s1, data=request.data)
        except MySerializer.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        if serializer.is_valid():
            if flag == 0:
                pass
            else:
               serializer.update(s1,validated_data=request.data)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)

urlpatterns = [path('temp/<int:pk>', ReadClass.as_view(), name = " reading"),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF has mixins for List, Create, Retrieve, Update and Delete functionality. Generic views just combine these mixins. You can choose any subset of these mixins for your specific needs. In your case, you can write your view like this, if you only want Create and Retrieve functionalty:

```
class ReadClass(GenericAPIView, CreateModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin):
    queryset = MyCModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This would provide default functionality for post and get requests. If you prefer, you can override post method like you did in your example to customize post requset behavior.

You can read more about mixins and generic views [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createapiview)

Comment: I understand what you mean, even so after implementing it I can only post and it says `"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."`. Additionally, it says `Allow: POST, OPTIONS` . No `GET`

Comment: Retrieve method is used to retreive a single item, not a list. So to retreive, you need to send a request to /view_path/id

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. I can see the retrieve working in `retrieveupdatedestroy` with the url of type `view_path/id` but not in model mixins

Comment: Can you post your urls.py and updated view definition?

Comment: I've edited my answer, please note the added get and post methods

Comment: While this did work but what was the difference between the two! Doesn't it have its own built in `GET`?

Comment: Mixins provide methods like retrieve / list / create / update / destroy, you need to link requests methods to those methods when subclassing GenericAPIView. But if instead if you use viewsets and subclass GenericViewSet along with mixins, you do not need to write methods like get / post etc., but you need to make url bindings in a different way in that case, making use of routers